# How to Get Array of Stylesheets and Scripts in wp_head & wp_footer

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

We need to be able to be able to fetch an array of all stylesheets/scripts loaded by the wp_head/wp_footer functions both using PHP from the functions.php file in the WordPress theme. Is there a way to do this? My reason for doing this is we have a custom PHP script for minifying and combining them that our client would like to continue to use that's built right into the WordPress theme itself (without any need for plugins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this two filters you can get all loaded js/css files.

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 );

function vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js( $src ) {
   return $src;
}
```

in that function you get the url of css/js files. i hope this hooks is useful for you.

i find this code from [here](http://matword.com/wordpress-remove-query-string-css-javascript/)

Comment: Very nice I've been looking for something like this for a couple days between work.  Thank you very much